# How to find the least shopped month in a csv file with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv, data-science

I have a csv file called purchases.csv and I am trying to find the least and most shopped months. I added the csv file to the end of the question. Here what i got so far;

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.read_csv('purchases.csv')

df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']) #Filtering the date to 2020 only
dataset=df[df['date'].dt.year == 2020]

#Exploratory Data Analysis

totalShop = len(dataset) # Total shopping
print(totalShop)

product = len(dataset['item_id'].value_counts()) #How many products there are
print(product) # Ürün Sayısı

count = Counter(dataset['item_id']) #most selled 10 products
maxSold = count.most_common(10)
print(maxSold)
```

I believe I can find it with counter and most_common() but it does not work well. This is what I tried;

```
count = Counter(dataset['date'])
maxShopping = count.most_common()
print(maxShopping)
```

I would appriciate if anyone can help me. Thank you so much!

[image: This is what the csv file looks like]

Comment: what does your data look like? It is impossible to tell you what approach would suit you without data.

Comment: Oh! You are totally right, I am editing the question

Comment: Could you edit your question again and put the data in text form rather than image, so it is easier for people to copy paste it.